# WCF Test Client Hangs While Loading Service Contract

Tags: c#, wcf, wcftestclient

I am writing a C# WCF web service.  While debugging the application, I found that the WCF test client that ships with Visual Studio sometimes freezes while loading the service contract.  The progress bar for adding the service gets to around 50% and then hangs.  This does not always happen, but once it does, then I can't control it through Visual Studio.  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If your service contract is throwing exceptions, these exceptions can sometimes result in an additional process being run that blocks the WCF test client from adding the web service.

To fix this, go into the Task Manager and stop all instances of "ASP Development Server".